# В каких единицах измеряется интерес к вопросу, а также качество самого вопроса? Немного статистики

Tags: обсуждение

(1)  Если все ваши вопросы имеют **только один ответ**, то об этом стоит задуматься.  Лучше, если отвечающих несколько.

(2) Если все ваши вопросы имеют **только один голос,** то это о чем-то говорит.
Лучше, когда голосов много.

(3) Если все ваши принятые ответы принадлежат **одному-двум  участникам,** то почему?  Как вы делаете свой выбор? Может,  вы излишне доверяетесь отдельным людям и попали под их влияние?

(4) Если на ваш вопрос дают **мгновенный ответ,** то какой он? Вероятно, очень простой и легкий. Над ним не надо думать.

(5) Если у вашего вопроса **нет комментариев,** если он не вызывает споры и обсуждения,  то почему? Вероятно, он актуален не для всех.

(6) Если на все ваши вопросы есть ответы **в справочнике Розенталя,** то о чем это говорит? Вы  недостаточно знаете **правила**? Не привыкли работать самостоятельно, но любите рассчитывать на чужую помощь? Или же ваш вопрос **творческим** не назовешь?

А какие у вас **критерии для хороших **ВОПРОСОВ**?**

Comment: Логичность рассуждений и ссылка на правила по-возможности. Но и конечно стаж участника здесь. Это мое личное мнение.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.  Но какое значение имеет стаж? Новые участники  могут задать вопрос очень высокого качества. Примеров достаточно.  Ссылки?  Есть общеизвестные темы, на которые можно взглянуть по-новому, Сломать общепринятый шаблон – это очень творческий подход) Это мое личное мнение)

Comment: Я не говорю об участнике, задающий вопрос. Я имею виду отвечающего. Задать интересный вопрос может любой.

Comment: Здесь многие дают правильные ответы. Но самые сложные вопросы отвечают и отвечали единицы. Жаль, некоторых здесь нет. Особенно Людмилы. Называть имена остальных не хочу. Думаю, вы и сами знаете, о ком речь..

Comment: *на самые сложные. Ну вот обратно торопился.

Comment: Мне жаль многих, которых сейчас здесь нет, а форум так нуждается в хороших специалистах. Имена называть не хочу, здесь у каждого субъективный взгляд.  Люди не ангелы, драматизма всегда хватало,  Кто-то был за школьную правильность, но были и яркие индивидуальности.  В хорошем супчике каждому овощу должно быть место. Но ведь речь была о вопросах, а не об ответах. К примеру, вам не хочется самому разбирать справочник и вы постоянно ждете помощи от других. А кто-то увидел в правилах нечто большее, чем школьную программу и хочет это обсудить. Чей вопрос более ценен?

Comment: Мне второй более интересен. Если на форуме люди могут узнать что-то новое, вот что прекрасно. Это настоящее творчество. А школьные темы и на других ресурсах есть. И если это не так, то зачем вообще говорить о качестве вопросов. Пусть спрашивают, что хотят. Мне неохота самой с правилами разбираться, вот и пусть мне помогают.

Comment: Значит, я неверно понял  ваш вопрос. Особых критерий нет.  Но больше всего мне нравятся вопросы Игоря Болотого и еще один парень здесь есть. Имя не вспомню. Но вы отвечали на его вопросы.

Comment: Мне кажется, вопросы должны содержать грамотно составленный текст( и не содержать лишнего, того что к вопросу не относится) и об этом должен заботиться сам автор вопроса, а не нарочито содержать неведомые описки и ошибки. Также вопросы, ответы на которые ищутся единственному запросу в поисковике, не являются ценными, либо они должны быть сформулированы в общем виде с отсылкой на правило и тп, с указанием в чём конкретно сложность. Иначе кошачий автор вопроса создает много напряжения и мусорной работы, которая, увы, не забавна. Но я тут новенький и стажа не имею, потому это просто моё мнение.

Comment: Но основная проблема всё же, что кошачьего сознания слишком много), хочется немного больше человеческого, а то одни ребусы и многие с ошибками.

Comment: В целом вы правы. Я за информационный стиль вопросов, а живое общение более уместно в комментариях.  Но к нашему котику вы чересчур строги))  В его вопросах нет шаблонного сознания, свойственного многим людям, а это, согласитесь, тоже немало.

Comment: Да я согласен, вопрос деликатный, но одно дело, когда это бред, но по делу, а другое дело когда это нарочитый бред из ничего с кучей специальных ошибок, неясно для чего. То есть до определенной степени бред должен быть отредактирован самим автором, иначе это ни в какие ворота не лезет. Тут же всё-таки не сеанс совместно шизофрении от русского языка. Или это игра такая, кто-то играет в кота, я буду в Буратино играть, а вы тогда кем будете? Можно так, чтобы каждый нёс свой нефильтрованный бред)

Comment: Да, вы правы, бредовые вопросы и бредовые игры в котов продолжаются. Закрывать и минусовать – вот решение)

Answer (score 1):

В ходе дискуссии по теме

```
    Но больше всего мне нравятся вопросы Игоря Болотова и 
  еще один парень здесь есть. Имя не вспомню. Но вы отвечали 
  на его вопросы. –
```

Серж, мне эти ребята тоже **очень нравятся**. Я их имела в виду, когда писала: **других тем не видно.**

Сейчас на форуме **так много информационного шума**, что им здесь работать невозможно. **Поток сиюминутных действий**: задан вопрос, через минуту готов ответ (думать-то особенно не надо!), через минуту ответ принят. Следующий!

А кто и чему научился, что нового узнал? Никто и ничего? **Как с этим бороться?** Вот и приходят сюда некоторые люди не за знаниями, а репутацию зарабатывать.

Я не против **текущих вопросов**, они очень разные. Есть действительно **интересные**, я сама на такие отвечаю. Но их уж **очень много,** да и сортировать по качеству приходится.

Тогда надо делать **выбор!** **Закрывать и минусовать** то, что выглядит откровенно плохо и неряшливо.

И про **стиль вопросов** стоит вспомнить. Давайте скажем "нет!" всем этим "запятушонкам" и чересчур свободному оформлению.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** **от 29.12.2023**

Наш небезызвестный участник опубликовал свой девиз: **«Нипочём непобедимы мы!».**

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478347/Вот-наш-девиз-Нипочём-непобедимы-мы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478347/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D1%8B)

И надо сказать, **что он прав.** Пока будут находиться **отвечающие** на его вопросы, он **непобедим**. Мы ничего не сможем сделать с подобной ситуацией.

Вот пример: принятый ответ с грубой грамматической ошибкой [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478338/Окотить-рисунок-значит-сделать-его-покошачье-покошачее](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478338/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%8C%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B5)

Поэтому "кошачья тема" открыто **демонстрирует свою силу.**

Comment: Я с вами согласен. Некоторые шаблонные вопросы стоит закрывать.. Но, увы, и на эти шаблонные ответы найдется тот, кто ответит.

Comment: Если вовремя закрыть, то не успеют ответить. Ну и минусовка будет предупреждением для автора. Вот задан очередной смам-вопрос на тему земля/Земля. Написала комментарий, пусть сам отвечает)